# How to fix out of scope variables?

Tags: java

Here is my code :

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class newCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String stored = scan.nextLine();

    print();

    }

    public static void print() {

        System.out.println(stored);

    }

}
```

---

I am using eclipse and I am wondering why I cannot do this, I understand it is out of scope or whatever but how can I get this to work without putting my sysout statement in my `main` function.

Comment: I am new to the site as I am java, and I am wondering as to why my question is being downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always pass a value to your `print` method instead:

```
// inside of main:
print(stored);

public static void print(String stored) {
    System.out.println(stored);
}
```

The reason you have to is as you describe; `stored` inside of `main` is out of scope.  Without informing another method of the value you want to use, it has no way to access it.

Comment: It's normally not in my wont to ask, but is there any particular reason that this answer merits a downvote?  There are many valid approaches to solving this problem; passing values happens to be one that came most naturally to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `stored` at class level  :

```
  public class newCode {
    static String stored; // You have to declare it static to access directly it in static method or you can also use newCode object if it is not static
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        stored = scan.nextLine();

        print();

    }
```